# list of arrays in to single set in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list called `allproiList` in grails which contains elements which are themselves arrays of numbers.

I want to put all the individual numbers  of arrays of list into a single set.

How can I do this in groovy ?

Comment: A single set of what? Post examples of what your arrays look like and what you want to see.

Comment: A single set of numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
//input
def allproiList = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5, 7, 8], [2, 5, 6]]

//transform to Set
Set numsOnly = allproiList.flatten() as Set

//or if you just need List of uniq elements, you could do
//List numsOnly == allproiList.flatten().unique()

//check result
assert numsOnly.sort() == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: List<Long> allproiList = []
        Set<Long> numsOnly=[]
        .........................
     allproiList=this.class.collection.find([locId:llocId],[proiList:1,_id:0 ]).sort([locId:1]).collect{[proiList: it.proiList ]}
        numsOnly = allproiList.flatten()
        println("set size="+allproiList.size())
        println("proilist size="+numsOnly.size())    but it is not working for me. Still numsOnly.size() gives one to me.

Comment: sorry, don't understand your code. what's inside your `allproiList`?

Comment: allproiList contains arrays which again contains millions of integers of type long. Actually these integers are IP adderesses converted to long int.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from `List` to `Set`:

```
def result = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3].toSet()
assert result instanceof Set
assert result == [1, 2, 3] as Set
```

Reference:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#toSet()